Linking librdkafka with CMakeLists.txt
I am not able execute the cmake command containing the dependency to librdkafka
This is the error I get
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindRdKafka.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "RdKafka", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "RdKafka" with any
  of the following names:

    RdKafkaConfig.cmake
    rdkafka-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "RdKafka" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "RdKafka_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "RdKafka" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


This is my CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(kafka_producer_cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)


# Find librdkafka
find_package(RdKafka REQUIRED)
include_directories(${RDKAFKA_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Find OpenCV
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})


add_executable(producer producer.cpp)

target_link_libraries(producer ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${RDKAFKA_LIBRARIES})


librdkafka version 2.3.0 is installed
Also, I see that in my homebrew librdkafka folder, I can't find the .cmake file
$ find /opt/homebrew/Cellar/librdkafka/ -iname "*cmake"


But for the opencv module (for which the find_package is successful), I get this.
$ find /opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv -iname "*cmake"
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.9.0_6/lib/cmake
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.9.0_6/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVModules-release.cmake
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.9.0_6/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVConfig-version.cmake
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.9.0_6/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVConfig.cmake
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.9.0_6/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVModules.cmake


I used brew install librdkafka to install the Apache Kafka C/C++ library

Does rdkafka normally provide CMake support? You might have to go through pkg-config.

I assume that by librdkafka you are referring to this repository.
From what I can see, the repository does not contain a cmake config file.
This means that the intended use is to build the sources yourself, and to link to the library as part of your own project.
To do this, you have to add the source code to your own project and link to the library (rdkafka++) as you would with any library you would have written yourself.

Correction:
As Tsyvarev pointed out, the cmake config file is actually getting generated by CMake inside the librdkafka project.
Could it be that you have forgotten to configure & build the project?

"From what I can see, the repository does not contain a cmake config file." - It actually creates the config file at CMakeLists.txt:253.

@Tsyvarev You are right, that is my bad. Then the problem must be that he hasn't built the librdkafka project yet.
